# Customer Group Restriction

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, customer-group

I want to apply some rule for customer group for example if general user can buy only single quantity of any product and wholesaler can buy limitless  product quantity and retail can buy specific quantity and so on for different customer groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Magento Provide By default functionality.

To set this kind of Functionality.

**Step 1:** Login Into your Magento Admin Panel.

**Step 2:** Go to `System >> Configuration >> Inventory Tab`.

**Step 3:** Find Tab `Product Stock Options` Click on that.

[image]

**Step 4:** Now Click on `Add Minimum Qty`.

**Step 5:** Select Customer Group and and based on that select the Qty.

[image]

**Step 6:** Now Save Configuration and Refresh the Cache.

Let me know if any more help.

Comment: thanx, but this is for minimum quantity can we manage for max quantity.

Comment: for that you have to enhance this functionality

Comment: can you guide on this..

Comment: I have never develop this kind of functionality I need to do some research on that

Comment: ok, if got info on above topic just let me know

Comment: yes sure :) ...........