# Quantity increments by customer group

Tags: magento-1.9, qty-increment

We have consumer customer group and wholesale customer group. How can I implement quantity increments by product AND restrict it by customer group? Or exclude customer group from quantity increments. I googled 1000 hours for an extension but it doesnt exist.

Comment: If I correctly understand you need this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37046/customer-group-restriction